# Error: Failed to create capture session

Tags: java, android

I am using below code in order to capture image:

```
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, mImageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                if(mCameraDevice == null){
                    return;
                }
                try{
                    mPreviewCaptureRequest = mPreviewCaptureRequestBuider.build();
                    mCameraCaptureSession = session;
                    mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                            mPreviewCaptureRequest,
                            mSessionCaptureCallback,
                            mBackgroundHandler
                    );
                }catch(CameraAccessException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "create camera session failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, null);
```

> Error: Failed to create capture session

In setup camera. I have:

```
Size largestImageSize = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new Comparator<Size>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
         return Long.signum(lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() - rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }
}
);
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largestImageSize.getWidth(), largestImageSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
```

I think the problem is with getting surface from `mImageReader`. But, I don't know what to do here!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the following on you manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes. I am using camera2